# Fetch list of statuses Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

On the Facebook open graph, I am able to use the call

```
/me? fields=statuses.limit(50).fields(likes)
```

in order to fetch a list of the likes  on the last 50 statuses of the user. However, when I try to actually use the call in my Facebook app with

```
FB.api('/me?fields=statuses.limit(50).fields(likes)', function(response) {
          console.log(response);
});
```

the list remains unpopulated. I already got permission for the user's status. When I try to get something else like a list of the user's friends, that works. Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **FQL Query** to get status messages Facebook provide against your profile:

```
**SELECT status_id, message, time  FROM status WHERE uid = me() ORDER BY time asc LIMIT 50**
```

you can sort result as well using other param.

**PHP code:**

```
**$status_q = "SELECT status_id, message, time  FROM status WHERE uid = me() ORDER BY time asc LIMIT 50";
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $status_q);
//Run Query
$result =  $facebook->api($params);**

$facbook is the FB object you create while initializing FB sdk.
```